# Prevent Save/Close of an excel file when certain cells are empty

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying prevent my excel file from saving and closing without filling in data into one column by using VBA.

I have a sheet named "Action Tracker" that contains a table called "tb_Action_Tracker".

Column K is named "Current Status", and it contains a dropdown menu, where you can choose from sevel statuses (New, Open, At Risk, Overdue, Closed).

My target is: In case that someone will add a new row/data set into the table, and choose any of the statuses in column K (named "Current Status") then it will not be possible to close/save the file without filling in the information into the column L named "Last update".

In other words: If I add a new row into the table, then I will select status "New" (or any other from the dropdown menu) in column K, and will leave column L empty, then I will get a warning message saying "xyz".

Does somebody know how to solve this issue?

This is my code but it does not work:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Sheets("Action Tracker").Select

Dim tbl As ListObjects
Set tbl = Sheets("Action Tracker").ListObjects("tb_Action_Tracker")

If ListObjects("tb_Action_Tracker").Column("Last update").Value = "" Then
Cancel = True

MsgBox "Save cancelled"
Else
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End If

End Sub
```

I am gonna be thankful for any hint! :)

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to count the blank cells in the column:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Sheets("Action Tracker").ListObjects("tb_Action_Tracker").ListColumns("Last update").Range) > 0 then 
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "Save cancelled"
Else
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True`, since this is the `BeforeClose` event, so it's already started to close.  (You may still want `ThisWorkbook.Save` there though - `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook calling the code, so is safer than using `ActiveWorkbook`)

If you set `Cancel = True`, then it will cancel the Close - if you want to cancel the *Save*, then you will need something similar in the `BeforeSave` event.

Now, you want to reject Save/Close when a row exists that fulfils the following 3 conditions:

1. Not Row 1 (e.g. *Column K is not "Current Status"* or *Column K is not "Last Update"*)
2. Column K is **not** blank
3. Column L **is** blank

Well, let's write that as a `COUNTIFS`:

```vb
=COUNTIFS($K:$K, "<>" & $K$1, $K:$K, "<>", $L:$L, "")
```

You can use Excel Worksheet functions in VBA with `WorksheetFunction.<FunctionName>`, so convert the above:

```vb
WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("Action Tracker").Columns(11), "<>" & Worksheets("Action Tracker").Cells(1,11).Value, Worksheets("Action Tracker").Columns(11), "<>", Worksheets("Action Tracker").Columns(12), "")
```

If that formula gives us 1 or more, then we have an invalid row, so we want to disable saving & closing!  Stick it all together, and here you go:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Action Tracker").Columns(11), "<>" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Action Tracker").Cells(1, 11).Value, _
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Action Tracker").Columns(11), "<>", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Action Tracker").Columns(12), "") > 0 Then
        Cancel = True
    'Else 'Optional - if you uncomment this it will always save when you close
    '    ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Action Tracker").Columns(11), "<>" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Action Tracker").Cells(1, 11).Value, _
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Action Tracker").Columns(11), "<>", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Action Tracker").Columns(12), "") > 0 Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```